# Lottery Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css, random

I have to make some kind of a lottery in javascript, html and css. My html and css are already done, the problem is that I don't know how to generate random numbers and show the previous roll. In the end it should look like this:[image: End] So when pushed on the button that should pop up. This is my other code ([html and css](https://codepen.io/TIHOW1/pen/rNNbMqm))

The only thing I need is the javascript.

Html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Hipster powered lottery</title>

    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="assets/css/reset.css"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/style.css" type="text/css"/>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"/>
    <script src="assets/js/main.js"></script>

</head>
<body>
<div id="container" class="cf">
    <header>
        <h1>Hipster Powered Lottery</h1>

    </header>

    <section>
        <h2>Play with our wonderful lottery est. 1831</h2>
        <a href="#" id="generate" onclick="generatenumbers()">Generate my numbers!</a>
        <ul id="generated"></ul>

    </section>
    <aside>
        <h2>Previously generated set</h2>
        <ul id="previous"></ul>

    </aside>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

CSS:

```
/*---------------------*/
/*   GENERAL ELEMENTS  */
/*---------------------*/


body {
    font-family: "Palatino Linotype", "Book Antiqua", Palatino, serif;
    font-size: 1rem;
    color: #333333;
    background-color: #FFFFFF;
    padding-top: 1px;
    padding-bottom: 25px;
    background-image: url(../media/bg.gif);
}

h1 {
    background-image: url(../media/hipster-powered-lottery.png);
    background-position: top left;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    height: 196px;
    width: 395px;
    text-align: center;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-bottom: 15px;

    text-indent: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
    white-space: nowrap;
    line-height: 1%;
}

h2 {
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 1.4rem;
    text-align: center;
    margin-bottom: 15px;
}
/*---------------------*/
/*   GENERAL CLASSES   */
/*---------------------*/

.cf:before,
.cf:after {
    content:"";
    display:table;
}

.cf:after {
    clear:both;
}

.column {
    float: left;
}

.hide {
    display: none;
}

.errormessage {
    color: #FF0000;
}


/*---------------------*/
/* CONTAINING ELEMENTS */
/*---------------------*/

#container {
    width: 75%;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-top: 30px;
}

/*------------------------*/
/* PAGE SPECIFIC ELEMENTS */
/*------------------------*/

/* --- Generation --- */
#generate {
    text-align: center;
    width: 20%;
    display: block;
    background-color: #3c3c3c;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    text-decoration: none;
    border: 1px solid #3c3c3c;
    border-radius: 5px;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    font-weight: bold;
    line-height: 35px;
    padding: 3px;
    margin-bottom: 25px;
}

#generate:hover {
    background-color: #c83c3c;
    border-color: #c83c3c;
}
#generated {
    text-align: center;
    margin-bottom: 25px;
}
#generated li, #generated span {
    background-image: url(../media/number.png);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: center center;
    background-size: 101px;
    width: 101px;
    height: 101px;
    text-align: center;
    line-height: 101px;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    display: inline-block;
    margin-right: 25px;
    font-size: 1.6rem;
}

#generated .joker {
    background-image: url(../media/joker.png);
    width: 100px;
    height: 115px;
    line-height: 115px;
    background-size: 100px 115px;
    display: block;
    margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto;
    font-size: 2rem;
}


/* --- previous --- */
#previous {
    text-align: center;
}
#previous ul {
    margin-bottom: 10px;
}

#previous li, #previous .joker {
    display: inline;
    font-size: 1.6rem;
}
#previous li:after {
    content: " - "
}

#previous li:last-child:after {
    content: ""
}
```

Thanks

Comment: Please do not post images of code, copy your code into the question with block code format:   https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: You can use [Math.random](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/random) and multiply it by the total number balls(?) there are. You can then store that random number in an array and do it `n` times while checking if the number already exists in the array. As for the previously generated set, you can store that in another variable.

Answer (score 0):

```js
function GenerateLottery() {
                            var chr1 = Math.ceil(Math.random() * 40)+ '';
                            var chr2 = Math.ceil(Math.random() * 40)+ '';
                            var chr3 = Math.ceil(Math.random() * 40)+ '';
                            var chr4 = Math.ceil(Math.random() * 40)+ '';
                            var chr5 = Math.ceil(Math.random() * 40)+ '';
                            var chr6 = Math.ceil(Math.random() * 40)+ '';
                          

                            var captchaCode = chr1 + ' ' + chr2 + ' ' + chr3 + ' ' + chr4 + ' ' + chr5 + ' '+ chr6;
                            document.getElementById("txtLottery").value = captchaCode
                            }
```

```html
<body onload="GenerateLottery();">
<input class="form-control" disabled="" id="txtLottery" style="text-align: center; border: none; font-weight: bold; font-family: Modern; display:inline-block; pointer-events:none;" type="text">
</body>
```

Change the number 40 to your maximum number, This is all the help im giving, good luck adding this to your code.